# PHP / Linux shell text colors

Tags: php, ubuntu, colors

I was wondering if there's a way of "coloring" the text coming out of php's stdout... (on ubuntu)
Basically I've got a scrapping script I made but I'd like to make it look nicer using different colors for different things.

http://cfgfactory.com/images/i/1de3b_colorz.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`Jm_Console`](https://github.com/metashock/Jm_Console#readme) package. It's a library that I wrote on my own.

Features:

- It supports console colors, console text decorations and has additional features like cursor positioning, or line / screen erasing (clear).
- You can install it using the [pear installer](http://www.metashock.de/pear/)  or [composer](https://packagist.org/packages/metashock/jm_console) or just [download the sources](https://github.com/metashock/Jm_Console#readme)
- It will work on all Linux or Mac systems and on Windows using [ansicon](https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon)
- It is well tested and released under the BSD-3 license.

enjoy :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to embed ANSI control sequences in your output to change the terminal color:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code

This generally involves the control sequence (`ESC(0x1b)` + `[`) and a formatting character, such as `ESC` + `[` + `32` + `m`

Note that this should be optional, ideally detecting if the stdout is not a terminal and turn off color automatically, as it makes using the output with scripts and log files difficult.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Console Color](http://pear.php.net/package/Console_Color) extension from PEAR